# How to run a vbscript file in Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, vbscript, taskscheduler

I want to run my VBS file script in the background on a specific date.

my VBS file is simple (call to the batch file and  run it in mode invisible)

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Temp\Generate_Report.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

PS: when I run the VBS file manually it works well but if I want to run it with TASK Scheduler I got this error.
[image]

Configuration file (VBS in the Task Scheduler  tool)
[image]

Comment: You will need to show us how you configured the task in Task Scheduler.  I hope you are using cscript.exe.  Also, this is not a batch-file question. I am removing that tag.

Comment: Done, Please take a look

Comment: On the General tab how do you have it configured to run?  Also, I gave you a hint in the my previous comment.  You should really use `cscript.exe` and pass the vbscript file as an argument.

Comment: or wscript.exe https://superuser.com/questions/1149959/is-it-possible-to-use-task-scheduler-to-open-a-vbs-file-without-a-command-window

Comment: how to create cscript.exe I'm quite new in this field

Comment: Cut and paste the value in `Program/script:` to `Add arguments (optional):`. In the `Program/script:` box type `cscript.exe`. However, if all you're doing is running the .bat file, you can just put that in the `Program/script:` box.

Comment: Thanks Squashman!  using cscript.exe and passing the vbs file as an argument worked for me.  I still don't know why hitting the vbs script directly works on one of my machines, but not the other.  But this way of doing it works great!